# react-router-dom useEffect dependency

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

### I'm trying to validate a JWT token on component render, if found in localStorage

Im doing this using a `useEffect()` hook, and a `useNavigate()` hook from the `react-router-dom` library. Here is the code:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const bbw = localStorage.getItem('bbw');
  
      const decodedToken = decodeToken(bbw);
      const decodedNumber = decodedToken.phoneNumber;
      setPhoneNumber(decodedNumber);
  
      const bbwVerify = isExpired(bbw);
      setValid(!bbwVerify);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      navigate('/');
    }
  }, [navigate]);
```

#### Console Error:

`You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered.`

I have tried to add the `setPhoneNumber` state variable to the dependency array to see if it changed anything, but it hasn't. I have also tried adding a timeout for the `navigate()` function call. Defining navigate within the useEffect hook leads to more errors.

#### Additional error, given that `navigate()` is not in the dependency array:

`React Hook useEffect contains a call to 'setPhoneNumber'. Without a list of dependencies, this can lead to an infinite chain of updates. To fix this, pass [navigate] as a second argument to the useEffect Hook`

#### Notes:

A `window.location.href` call is not a solution.
I'm thinking that a useCallback hook could be a solution, but I have not been able to implement it for `navigate()`.

Comment: @Dominic I added the react-router-dom tag, but I shall mention it explicitly in the post. Thanks

Comment: Ah sorry missed that

Comment: How often does this useEffect need to run? Have you tried passing an empty dependency array so that it only runs once after the first render?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. It only needs to run once, but not including navigate() in the dependency array leads to the additional error which I specified in the post.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to clarify because there's a difference between not providing a dependency array and providing an empty dependency array. I was under the impression that providing `[]` would do the trick

Comment: Yeah, thank you it's appreciated.

Comment: Is `uuseEffect` just a typo in the question? The error is saying that you are calling a `navigate` function outside the `useEffect` *somewhere* in your code. Does the error include a stacktrace that might indicate where exactly or in what file the call was incorrectly made? This post needs more debugging details.

Comment: @DrewReese `uuseEffect` was a typo in the question. I have also included the warning stack trace.

Comment: Looks like the issue is in some `Dashboard` component. Can you [edit] to include this `Dashboard` component as part of a relevant [mcve]? Have you searched your code for any `navigate` calls that are not in a callback or `useEffect` hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The issue was due to the way I was handling my return() statement.

Here is what I had **before**:

```
return validated ? (
    <div className="c-wrapper a-wrapper">
      {/* return code */}
    </div>
  ) : navigate("/");
```

Here is how I **fixed** it:

```
return validated ? (
    <div className="c-wrapper a-wrapper">
      {/* return code */}
    </div>
  ) : <></>
```

Simple solution to something I did not notice at the end of my code.

Answer (score 0):

found on Reddit

Navigate is a component wrapped around useNavigate. Which is what I think you’re trying to use.

> ```
> import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
> ```

In your

> return (<Navigate to="/" replace={true} />)